# Including a module that has dependencies as an entry point in Webpack (Angular 2 Typescript)

Tags: angular, webpack

I have configured Webpack in my project, and in the entry point field, I have added polyfills, vendor and app files. But I have another file 'myComponent.js' which has dependencies in it.

**webpack.common.js**

```
entry: 
    {
        'polyfills': './polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
        'components': './myComponent'
    },
resolve: 
    {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts', '.d.ts']
    }
```

And here is the component file that has a dependency--

**myComponent.js**

```
exports.EventDispatcher = require('./lib/EventDispatcher').EventDispatcher;
```

Now when I import this from my main component--

**app.component.ts**

```
import {EventDispatcher} from 'components';
```

Now when I run this **npm run build**, it gives me the following error

Module not found: Error: a dependency to an entry point is not allowed.

Any suggestions where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't require an entry point, in this case `components`, as a dependency in webpack. You can work around this by specifying components as an array [like so](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/300#issuecomment-45313650):

```
entry: 
    {
        'polyfills': './polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
        'components': ['./myComponent']
    }
```

Comment: Haha. I was having trouble with that error message and could never have figured it out. That is a very small detail. I had a different project where I did not have any errors and it indeed had an array for the `entry:` key. Thank you so much!